# MySQL: Update finds matches, but does not make changes. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, innodb

**Configuration:**
WAMP Server on WinServer 2008 R2, MySQL v5.1.36
I'm running my query directly in the MySQL Terminal.
The table being targeted is an *InnoDB* table, and the field being set is a lookup field against a string FK.

**Challenge:**
The query results say that there are a bunch of matches, but that no changes are being made.
What am I missing?

BTW: My experience level with MySQL Terminal is quite limited. In fact, I'm really only using it now because PhpMyAdmin chokes on the query (time exceeded throwing PMA session error).

**Code:**
The SQL I'm using is extremely basic:

```
UPDATE `my_table_name` 
SET `vendor_type` = 'master'
WHERE `data_source` = 'Group One'
```

Here are the results of the query:

> Query OK, 0 Rows affected (15.94 sec)
>   Rows matched: 149947  Changed: 0 Warnings: 0

As you can see, there are almost 150k records that *"should"* be getting updated, but aren't.

Comment: what's the table schema?

Comment: what's the output of 'select count(*) from my_table_name where data_source='Group One';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps because they all have the value "master" already.

Comment: I am **SOOO** ashamed =) ... My first few attempts were in PMA. After erroring out the first time, that col was still showing null. My subsequent attempts in PMA errored out too, and I guess I ASSumed the same results :-| ... anyhow thanks a million for shining some light on my incompetence =D

Comment: Well, there's a reason that I knew the answer...  it happens to everyone sometime!